# An attempt was made to set a data set parameter '@BrandName' that is not defined in this data set?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2008, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I'm trying to get data based on the parameter passed in the Power BI report server.

In the SSRS it was working fine

[image: Click here]

And I have set parameter like below in the shared dataset:

[image: Visual studio]

But in the Power BI report server, I'm getting an error like below

[image: Shared dataset properties]

Below is query written in my shared dataset
[image: click here]

Below is the parameter column for the shared dataset
[image: click here]

Comment: Can we see the part of the query where the parameter is being used?

Comment: @thmspl please see my updated question.